# How do I customize iNotes (forms9_x.nsf) to send an alterered e-mail

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am in the process of updating the forms9_x.nsf database to mimic some functionality that we've customized for the Notes client.  I've added an action button to the e-actions-mailedit menuid (new memo) that will append a value to the Subject field and then send the new memo.  I've got the update to the subject working fine, but don't know what to do to get the memo sent.  I've tried xxForm.submit() but I get an error message.  Here's what my code in Custom_JS_Lite looks like:

```
function SendEncrypted(sId) 
{
var answer = confirm("This memo will be sent in encrypted format to everyone listed in the To, CC and BCC fields.  " +
  "Are you sure this is what you want to do?");
var x;

if(answer == true){
    alert("Yes, please encrypt");

    // Get the current backend document ID
    var oPanelManager = AAA.Fkb();
    var sContentID = oPanelManager.EdI.get('T').oPrev.sId;

    // Get the current UI document
    var oMainDoc = AAA.EcK;

    var subj = oMainDoc.getElementById('e-' + sContentID + '-subject').value;
    oMainDoc.getElementById('e-' + sContentID + '-subject').value =  "[encrypted] " + subj;
    var newsubj = oMainDoc.getElementById('e-' + sContentID + '-subject').value;
    alert("The new subject is " + newsubj);
    var oForm = oMainDoc.getElementById('e-pageui-' + sContentID);
    //oForm['tmpSendOptions'].value = "1"
    oForm.Submit();
    alert("Document submitted");       }
else{
    alert("The answer is cancel");}
return;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sandra

Answer (score -1):

```
oForm.submit();  // the submit method of the FORM object is lower case, your code shows ".**S**ubmit()"


// this should evaluate to the FORM object.
var oForm = oMainDoc.getElementById('e-pageui-' + sContentID);

// Does this display a value?
window.alert( oForm.Subject.value );
```

Comment: I actually found the answer in the LDD 8.5 forum.  Instead of oForm.submit(), used the following:  AAA.DSq.ELU(event, 'e-actions-mailedit', 'EbK', {sAction: 'a-send'});